# How to format-number to define thousands seperator?

Tags: php, number-formatting

I am a php noob (very) and i got following code:

```
<?echo getPointsColor($row["fld_points"])?>
```

Currently the number 1234 in the database is shown as 1,234, but i would like to have it 1234 (without as thousand seperator).

I found:

```
$english_format_number = number_format($number, 0, '.', '');
```

This would make it 1234 instead of 1,234

BUT i don't know how to change my code (first code above) to make it work. Can someone post me how the correct codechange would like like?

Info, here is the the function:

```
function getPointsColor($points_to_color)
{
    $myp = intval($points_to_color);

    if($myp <= 0)
        $myp = "<font color='#a71212\'>".number_format($myp,'\'')."</font>";
    else
        $myp = "<font color='#4ea712\'>".number_format($myp,'\'')."</font>";

    return $myp;
}
```

Comment: You would need to show an d make a change in `getPointsColor()`.  Nobody has any idea what that's doing.

Comment: Hi Abra, i have posted the function as code in my question, see above please. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You can do it like this:

```
$english_format_number = number_format($number, 2, '.', ',');
```

[Reference](http://php.net/manual/en/function.number-format.php)

The third parameter sets the decimal separator, the fourth sets the thousands separator.

Answer (score 0):

OK thanks to all!

I have edited the functions as following and it works:

```
function getPointsColor($points_to_color)
{
$myp = intval($points_to_color);

if($myp <= 0)
    $myp = "<font color='#a71212\'>".number_format($myp, 0, '.', '')."</font>";
else
    $myp = "<font color='#4ea712\'>".number_format($myp, 0, '.', '')."</font>";

return $myp;
}
```